# c# multiple constructors with same amount of parameter

Tags: c#

i know that i can't have constructors with same arguments. but for example class contains this

`public enum Brand { audi, bmw };
 public enum ModelAudi { /*some models*/ };
 public enum ModelBmw { /*some models */};`

i have multiple Model enums, and only one Brand. i don't know how to write constructor becouse it needs only Brand as argument and one Model depends on what Brand we choose.

```
    public Automobile(Brand brand,ModelAudi modelAudi)
{
    this.Brand = brand;
    this.ModelAudi = modelAudi;
}

public Automobile(Brand brand,ModelBmw modelBmw)
{
    this.Brand = brand;
    this.ModelBmw = modelBmw;
}

public Automobile(Brand brand,ModelAudi modelAudi,ModelBmw modelBmw)
{
    this.Brand = brand;
    this.ModelBmw = modelBmw;
    this.ModelAudi = modelAudi;
}
```

The first two constructors won't work because it has same arguments. The last one will work but it will have a lot empty(none) Model enums. so what is the best way to make it simply?

Comment: why can't you use one `Model` enum for all brands? In case of Audi, the ModelBmw value will always be empty right?

Comment: "_The first two constructors won't work because it has same arguments_" but `ModelAudi` is a different type than `ModelBmw` so yeah it _should_ work fine

Comment: The first two constructors WILL work. They both have two parameters, but the type of the second is different.

Comment: Normally this class would be abstract and the base class for all concrete models like `BMW`. Thiss class should not care about concrete models because an `Automobile` can be any model. The child-class'(f.e. `BMW:Autombile`) constructors could take them. But instead of enums i would use another class like `Model`.

Comment: Enums are problematic for many reasons. what will happen when you add another brand? or when Bmw come up with a new model?

Comment: I think your design is a bit too complicated. Why do you even need enums? Simple strings would do the same for you, simply create a interface that both brands implement and that defines a `Model`-property. Furtheremore: what would `new Autombile(new Brand { Name = Audi }, ModelAudi.Q5, ModelBMW.X3)` mean? Makes no sense to me at all so your third constructor is quite confusing/meaningless.

Comment: @HimBrom this will enable all sort of errors

Comment: What happens if a user writes `new Autombile(Brand.Audi, ModelBmw.X3)`?

Answer (score 1):

> The first two constructors won't work because it has same arguments.

No, it *doesn't* have the same parameters.  The second parameter is of a different type in each case, and so it compiles just fine.

Of course, in the first case you know the brand is Audi, and in the second case you know that it's BMW, so there's no need to accept a "Brand" parameter (not that it fails to compile in either case.

Comment: OP asked "_so what is the best way to make it simply_" and I don't see an answer

Comment: @FirstStep I describe two solutions for him to use, the one that he has, which works fine and meets the requirements he's given, and accepting an appropriate model in two overloads.

Answer (score 0):

When object construction itself requires some degree of logic - in this case more logic than the rest of the class contains - then it might make sense to separate the construction from the class. That's called the Builder pattern.

Many of the examples you'll find when you Google it address more complex scenarios. But in this case you're dealing with something a little simpler. You want the constructors to be used a little more specifically depending on what the value of certain enums is.

You could do something like

```
public class AutomobileBuilder
{
    //For the types that only need brand
    public Automobile BuildFord()
    {
        //call constructor, create Automobile
    }

    //For types requiring more options:
    public Automobile BuildAudi(AudiModel model)
    {
        //call constructor, create Automobile
    }
}
```

You could declare the `Automobile` constructor as `internal`, forcing consumers of your library to use the builder.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do one Model enum:

```
    public enum Brand { audi, bmw };
    public enum Model { /*All your models*/ };
```

Then your constructor:

```
public Automobile(Brand brand, Model Audi)
{
    this.Brand = brand;
    this.Model = Audi;
}
```

B.S You might need to rename/adjust your class design and member variables?